# EclipseLink JPA CriteriaQuery is creating an erroneous SQL query

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

I 'm trying to implement a generic filter system in Primefaces datatable using LazyDataModel for any entity but is giving me problems when trying to search fields involved in one to many relationships as it generates erroneous SQL queries, my code is as follows i will skip some parts not relevant to keep it as simple as posible:

The entitys are Client and Fault:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ges_fault")
public class Fault extends Item implements Serializable, ItemIf{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "client_id", nullable = true)
private Client client;

// Getters and setters
```

Client class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ges_client")
public class Client extends Item implements Serializable, ItemIf {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="client", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Fault> faults;

// Getters and setters
```

To abstract the problem the final criteria query looks as follow:

```
CriteriaBuilder qb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Fault> c = qb.createQuery(Fault.class);
Root<Fault> root = c.from(Fault.class);
c.select(root);
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
Expression<String> exp = root.get("client");
predicates.add(qb.like(exp,"%" + 1 + "%"));
c.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
List<Fault>result = q.getResultList();

return result;
```

The error i'm getting is:

> Internal Exception:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE '%1%' AND
>   (t0.ID = t1.client_id)) LIMIT 0, 12' at line 1

Error Code: 1064 Call:

> SELECT t1.ID AS a1, t1.NOMBRE AS a8, t1.client_id AS a9 FROM
>   ges_client t0, ges_fault t1 WHERE ( LIKE ? AND (t0.ID =
>   t1.client_id)) LIMIT ?, ?     bind => [3 parameters bound] Query:
>   ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Falta sql="SELECT t1.ID AS a1, t1.NOMBRE
>   AS a8, t1.client_id AS a9 FROM ges_client t0, ges_falta t1 WHERE (
>   LIKE ? AND (t0.ID = t1.client_id)) LIMIT ?, ?")   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:682)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)

Because what I'm trying to do to do I can not use this kind of querys:

```
Expression<String> exp = root.get(Fault_.client);
```

so it is not a possible solution.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: so EclipseLink creates some incorrect SQL. Try a different JPA implementation and see what that creates

Comment: What i can use on a glassfish server?

Comment: I appreciate your comment but usually change the implementation of JPA is not as simple as adding some libraries when it comes to a project of a certain size and hopefully spend a day or two just to change it, and probably will not solve the problem.

Comment: "probably will not solve it" ... you can easily VERIFY that by splitting the class + criteria code involved into a small self contained test and run it outside a container. I have plenty of criteria exmaples in my code like those you have there and don't get such errors with a different JPA provider

Comment: Please remove all the unnecessary code that is not relevant at all: facelets, primefaces, jsf and managed beans are not relevant to your problem that is merely related to JPA criteria queries.

Comment: Ok i have remove it, I added in case anyone think of another way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to filter on the Client's `name` property. In this case, use one of the following syntaxes, depending if you are using typesafe MetaModel or not:

```
Path<Client> client = root.get(Fault_.client);
Path<String> exp = client.get(Client_.name);
```

or:

```
Path<Client> client = root.get("client");
Path<String> exp = client.get("name");
```

In both situations you can avoid specifying the class in Path, or you can even avoid instantiating explicitly the client variable at all:

```
Path exp = root.get(Fault_.client).get(Client_.name);
```

or

```
Path client = root.get(Fault_.client);
Path exp = client.get(Client_.name);
```

are all legal, as well as their equivalent using attribute names `"client"` and `"name"` instead of metamodel.

Afterwards, proceed as you have already done for creating the `Predicate` expression.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but for this purppose I didn't want to specify the class on the Path, i will mark this answer as solution. But just for know, It is possible to do this without specifying the class in Path<Client>?